# Hibernate: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, entity-relationship

I have 2 classes: `Msg`and `Task` that are 1-to-1.

If i try to save Msg instance without setting Task instance for it i get.

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: entity3.Msg.task
```

How do i enable saving Msg without Task? i have this in mapping file for Msg but its not helping

```
<many-to-one class="entity3.Task" fetch="select" name="task" not-null="false">
  <column name="TaskID" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try modifying your mapping as below,

```
<many-to-one class="entity3.Task" fetch="select" name="task" 
column="TaskID" not-null="false"> </many-to-one>
```

The problem could be because you are having a `not-null="true"` at the `column` definition tag. Read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) more about hibernate mappings.

Comment: thanks for answer. what do i do in case of one-2-one. How do i modify mapping?

Comment: Read here about [one-to-one mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone).

Comment: it seems that one-2-one, dont have not-null option.